# How can I add parameters to a stored procedure using ADO.NET in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to execute my stored procedure which has an output parameter with ADO.NET in ASP.NET Core MVC. But I get an error saying that my stored procedure expects a parameter which I have already set.

My stored procedure is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSearch] 
    @Notes nvarchar(max) = NULL, 
    @StartDate datetime = NULL, 
    @EndDate datetime = NULL,
    @UserId nvarchar(450),
    @Result money OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@StartDate > @EndDate) 
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR (N'Start date cannot be greater than end date',16,1) 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        IF (@Notes IS NULL OR @Notes = '') 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT *
            FROM Expenses
            WHERE UserId = @UserId 
              AND [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
            ORDER BY [date] DESC 

            IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) 
            BEGIN 
                RAISERROR (N'No data found according to date match', 16, 1) 
            END 

            SELECT @Result = SUM(amount) 
            FROM Expenses 
            WHERE UserId = @UserId 
              AND [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            IF (@StartDate IS NULL OR @StartDate = '' OR @EndDate IS NULL OR @EndDate = '')
            BEGIN
                SELECT * 
                FROM expenses 
                WHERE UserId = @UserId 
                  AND Notes LIKE '%' + @notes + '%' 
                ORDER BY [date] DESC 

                SELECT @Result = SUM(amount) 
                FROM expenses 
                WHERE UserId = @UserId 
                  AND notes IN (SELECT notes 
                                FROM expenses 
                                WHERE notes LIKE '%' + @Notes + '%') 
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT *
                FROM   Expenses  
                WHERE UserId=@UserId and notes LIKE '%' + @notes + '%'   and [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
                                 ORDER  BY [date] DESC 
                        IF( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ) 
                        BEGIN 
                        RAISERROR(N'No matching record found',16,1) 
                        END 

                        SELECT @Result = Sum(amount) 
                        FROM   Expenses 
                        WHERE  Notes IN(SELECT Notes 
                              FROM   Expenses 
                             WHERE UserId=@UserId and  notes LIKE '%' + @Notes + '%') 
                        AND [date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
            END
       END
    END 
 END
```

My method is like:

```
public IQueryable<Expenses> SearchExpenses(string UserId, string Notes, DateTime startFrom, DateTime endTo)
    {
        List<Expenses> expenses = new List<Expenses>();
        using (DALC.GetConnection())
        {
            DALC.Command("[spSearch]");
            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add("@Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Notes;
            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startFrom;
            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endTo;
            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserId;//I set my sp paremeter here but why error?
            //Is This the correct way to set an output parameter?
            SqlParameter howMuch = new SqlParameter("@Result", SqlDbType.Money);
            howMuch.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            DALC.cmd.Parameters.Add(howMuch);
            DALC.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var result = Convert.ToDecimal(DALC.cmd.Parameters["@Result"]);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = DALC.cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                Expenses expense = new Expenses
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]),
                    Desription = reader["Notes"].ToString(),
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"]),
                    IsCash = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCash"]),
                    IsCard = Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsCash"]),
                    SearchResultOut = result
                };
                expenses.Add(expense);
            }
        }
        return expenses.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'spSearch'
> expects parameter '@UserId', which was not supplied.'

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Search(string UserId, string notes, DateTime startFrom, DateTime endTo)
    {
        UserId = GetUserId();
        context.SearchExpenses(UserId,notes,startFrom,endTo);            
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: can you show your DALC please?

Comment: Are you setting [CommandType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) to `StoredProcedure`?

Comment: @Sergey yeah sure but It is not the first time I use this [**class**](https://i.paste.pics/BGB41.png).. so far there hasn`t been a problem..

Comment: @Zer0 sure take [**a look**](https://i.paste.pics/BGB41.png)..

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating all the sql parameters in the same way.

For the Output parameter, you are doing it correctly by creating a sql parameter object and setting the direction.

You should try doing the same for the other parameters (without setting the direction of course)

**Debugging**

You should put a breakpoint right before execution and add a watch to the parameter collection of the cmd object to see what it looks like.

Also verify that the cmd object is of type stored procedure.

If all checks out, open up sql profiler and you should be able to see what is passed in via SQL profiler and grab the actual call to the stored proc with all its parameters.

Take the actual call and run on SSMS and see what it does.

This should help you figure it out.

Also when you get the result back, syntax is
var result = Convert.ToDecimal(DALC.cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);

Comment: Yeah, when in doubt I almost always check what exact command(s) the database is getting.  SQL Profiler is quite useful spotting issues that are harder to debug on the client-side.  Can save a lot of time simply looking at the generated SQL statement(s) the database is trying to execute.

Comment: Yep. Seems the many years of banging one's head against the proverbial wall had some upside.

Comment: @Chuma Yeah I had done it before I posted this question.. [This](https://i.paste.pics/BGB72.png) is controller breakpoint and [this](https://i.paste.pics/BGB7W.png) is my watch

Comment: @Chuma and it is been mentioned that the cmd object is an sp in the [dalc class](https://i.paste.pics/BGB41.png)

Comment: It seems your DALC class simply instantiates, returns and allows execution of a standard command object. So going step by step, have you put a watch and verified the settings of the command object and its parameter collection? What I see in the watch appears to be the parameters passed into the function but not the parameters of the command object before it executes. Also what does profiler show?

Answer (score 0):

In your "DALC" class "Command" method can not work correctly.
Because "command" value has got special character in the first letter.

```cs
            var commandwithspecialCharacter = "[spSearch]";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandwithspecialCharacter, new SqlConnection());
            if (commandwithspecialCharacter.StartsWith("sp")) {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"commandwithspecialCharacter==>{cmd.CommandType}");
```

First output **commandwithspecialCharachter==> Text**

```cs
            var commandwithoutspecialCharacter = "spSearch";
            if (commandwithoutspecialCharacter.StartsWith("sp")) {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"commandwithoutspecialCharacter==>{cmd.CommandType}");
```

Second output **commandwithoutspecialCharacter==>StoredProcedure**

In the startsWith method, the result is false because it has "[" character.
StartsWith control works correctly with "[sp" control in the "Command" method.

[image: Code block]